# Is a large Firestore transaction quicker in a Cloud Function or with client-side API?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, performance, google-cloud-firestore, transactions

I'm working on a React web app where we're using the Firebase SDK to perform some transactions that have to query and get a number of documents, then commit a handful of documents. When I record the perf, it looks like the "batchGet"s take about 150ms, then the commit takes about 150ms. That amount of time makes the interaction feel a bit laggy.

I'm wondering if there's any notable difference in perf when transactions are performed in Cloud Functions vs on the client? My logic being that doing a get/commit in a cloud function might be quicker simply due to being "closer" to the database (which may be a totally incorrect assumption), and so doing multiple reads/writes won't have the same round-trip cost as it does on the client.

Has anyone found cloud functions to be quicker for batches or transactions, or is it basically the same as on the client?

Comment: A lot depends on the code of the transaction handler, and the client in question. Without providing exact details about those in your question, you're more likely to be helped by trying both scenarios yourself and measuring.